# Datatables - Show a specific row at the top of the table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have Datatables running fine on one of my projects. I'm trying to display a certain row at the top of the table if it contains a certain string.

Is there any way to do this as I cannot find anything in the datatables documentation.

Comment: Seems like [Sorting with abolute position](https://datatables.net/blog/2016-12-22) does what you are after

Answer (score 2):

add a hidden column ,put a higher value in the specific row and use "aaSortingFixed". (I think in the new version is "orderFixed")

```
 <table>
  <thead>
    <th>
      <td class="hidden"></td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>age</td>
      <td>salary</td>
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden">100</td>
      <td>Taylor Murphy</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>$62k - $68k</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden">0</td>
      <td>Jared Henderson</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>$59k - $64k</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden">0</td>
      <td>Rolando Yates</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>$49k - $53k</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

here 100 is the higher value which we want stick it on top

```
$('table').DataTable( {
    "aaSortingFixed": [[0,'desc']]
});
```

now we can reOrder the table but the row with 100 value will be always on the top